how to use esbuild to build the bundle if importmap is used
Possible to use esbuild to build the bundle if importmap is used?
Below is my esbuild build script, it shows Error: Could not resolve "mylib", but how can I tell esbuild about the importmap?
await esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['../src-js/main.js'],
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  format: 'esm',
  outdir: '../js',
  outbase: '../src-js',
});

html:
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "mylib": "/src-js/my-lib.js"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module" src="/src-js/main.js"></script>

/src-js/my-lib.js:
export function say_hello() {
    alert('hello');
}

/src-js/main.js:
import { say_hello } from 'mylib';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    say_hello();
});

